# Generic Types with Abstract classes and Interfaces

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I have three classes, one base class which takes a generic type that must be a subclass of an abstract class which in turn takes a generic type that must implement an interface.

For testing I have a form which will initiate the base class giving a subclass of the abstract class and an implementation of the interface. Here are my class declarations, and call to the base class constructor.

```
    public class BaseClass<AC_IC> where AC_IC : AbstractClass<InterfaceClass>

    public abstract class AbstractClass<IC> where IC: InterfaceClass

    public interface InterfaceClass

    public class ExtendsAbstractClass<II> : AbstractClass<InterfaceClass>

    public class ImplementsInterface : InterfaceClass

    vBC = new BaseClass<ExtendsAbstractClass<ImplementsInterface>>();
```

I believed I would be able to create instances of both of the inheriting/implementing classes from within the BaseClass and AbstractClass using the following calls (only one class will have parameters in the constructor)

```
    (AC_IC) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(AC_IC), new object[] { vParameter});
    (II) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(II));
```

EDIT: The above calls are within the BaseClass and AbstractClass and therefore do not know which classes I will use subsequently, so cannot be specified by class name, there may be many different pairs of classes for a range of implementations.

For both of these constructor calls I get the errors 'Cannot create an instance of an abstract class' & 'Cannot create an instance of an interface'. How can I let the compiler know that the classes that I am passing as the generic types are subclassess of the classes in the `where` clauses and so can be created.

Any ideas community???

Answer (score 1):

The errors speak for themselves: You cannot create an instance of an abstract type.

You *CAN* cast the resulting type back to a base type, tho:

```
 (AC_IC) Activator.CreateInstance(
         typeof(BaseClass<ExtendsAbstractClass<ImplementsInterface>), 
         new object[] { vParameter});
```

EDIT:

```
public TFinal MakeMeA<TOuter,TInner,TInnermost,TFinal>(params object[] additionalCrap)
{
    // figure out innermost type
    var innermostType = typeof(TInner).MakeGenericType(typeof(TInnermost));
    // work outwards
    var nextLevel = typeof(TOuter).MakeGenericType(innermostType);
    // figure out what the heck we're making
    var returnType = typeof(TFinal).MakeGenericType(nextLevel);

    // And make one of those    
    return (TFinal)Activator.CreateInstance(returnType, additionalCrap);
}
```

Comment: I should have said, these two lines of code are in the BaseClass and AbstractClass classess, and so do not know that ExtendsAbstractClass and ImplementsInterface are being used, the idea is to create this solution as a framework and not specific to two classes

Comment: @ColinSteel Aha, I see where you are going, I think - you want to be able to "suss out" what the actual implementing class would be?

Comment: Yes, I thought using the parameterised generic types did that for me, its seems as though not.

Comment: @ColinSteel Edited to include a "make me a X of Y of Z of...." method - is that what you're referring to?

Comment: In your solution, can you specify which class names are the abstract/interface and subclass/implementation. Also are you suggesting this method go in the base class or abstract class

Comment: @ColinSteel it's just an example of how to create nested generic types - you'd have to wrangle the details to fit this class structure. Probably you'd only need one level of `MakeGenericType`, since you stated you planned to do this at each level's `ctor`